# Database data compressed with Perl "Compress::LZF" won't decompress in Java

Tags: java, perl, compression, lzf

I am trying to decompress data stored in a database that was originally compressed with the Perl [`Compress::LZF`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::LZF) module.

The problem is that the header on the compressed data doesn't appear to match what the [`com.ning.compress.lzf`](https://github.com/ning/compress) library expects.

Does anyone know a way of decompressing data that's been compressed using `Compress::LZF`?

Comment: Is something preventing you from using [`Compress::LZF::decompress`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::LZF)?

Comment: Have you been able to decompress the database contents in any way at all? I wouldn't jump to blaming the module.

Comment: Sinan, the data was initially compressed in Perl, but we're using a Java application to read it.

Comment: Borodin, I can compress/decompress as long as I'm using either Java or Perl to do both. The problem is when it's compressed with one language and decompressed with another.